# Is it possible to restrict the distance and duration of an eddystone URL being broadcast?

Tags: node.js, beacon, eddystone, eddystone-url

Is it possible to restrict the distance and duration of an eddystone URL being broadcast?

I've been trying using the https://github.com/don/node-eddystone-beacon library, but even after I terminate the script, the device keeps broadcasting the url. I've tried changing the `txPowerLevel` to try to limit the distance, but I either get nothing, or over 30m tested

Answer (score 0):

`txPowerlevel` is to control the distance of the broadcast radius.
`tlmPeriod` if I am not mistaken is the number of times the beacon will broadcast, then it will just stop.  If you are talking about the frequency of the signal being broadcasted, you might need to change the code of `beacons.js`.  Look for `TICK_INTERVAL` and increase/decrease the number there.